# How Spring Boot controller communicates with objects from other packages?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I have a POJO Java application, where some class (e.g. Model) periodically gets data via web sockets, processes this data (saves something into hash tables) and outputs the result into console ones a minute. So in the main method I create an object of the Model class model(inputData), establish connection, get data via web sockets, process data and make
 System.out.print (model(inputData).processed) by Timer.
 This solution works.

I want to do the same, but output to a webpage using Spring Boot.
For this purpose, I put the working solution into “data-processing” package, create another package (say, “data-representation”) with Spring Boot application from this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) . 
I can create model(input data) object in the main method of the SpringBootApplication class. 
Then I need to create a controller like this one:

```
@Controller
public class ResultDataController {

  @MessageMapping("/in")
  @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
  public ResultData resultData (InputData inputData) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new ResultData("Here must be " + model(inputData).processed);
  }
```

What will be the structure of my application? How to get this model(inputData).processed into the controller?
Thank you in advance.